# Apache Pig Equivalent of Select *

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to get data through Pig. There are > 8K fields in the file and I wanted to select the top 10 records of each column:

Currently, I am just loading the entire table and spelling out the variable names, is there an equivalent to SQL's 
    `select * from TABLE LIMIT 10;`
in Pig?

Current Load
    `data = load 'xsf://EXAMPLE/1' using SomePigLoader('2017-01-01','2017-01-03','ID1,ID2,ID3....')`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.After loading use [LIMIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#LIMIT) on the relation

```
data = load 'xsf://EXAMPLE/1' using SomePigLoader('2017-01-01','2017-01-03','ID1,ID2,ID3....');
data_top10 = LIMIT data 10;
DUMP data_top10;
```